# void return value from a function used as input to a templated function is seen as a parameter

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

Say you have some target class with some methods on it:

```
class Subject
{
public:
  void voidReturn() { std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<std::endl; }
  int  intReturn()  { std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<std::endl; return 137; }
};
```

And a Value class (similar in concept to Boost.Any):

```
struct Value
{
  Value() {}
  Value( Value const & orig ) {}
  template< typename T > Value( T const & val ) {}
};
```

And I want to produce a Value object using a method from the Subject class:

```
Subject subject;
Value intval( subject.intReturn() );
Value voidVal( subject.voidReturn() );  // compilation error
```

I get the following errors in VC++2008:

```
error C2664: 'Value::Value(const Value &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void' to 'const Value &'
Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other types
```

and gcc 4.4.3:

```
/c/sandbox/dev/play/voidreturn/vr.cpp:67: error: invalid use of void expression
```

The context for this is when you want to use it inside a templated class:

```
template< typename Host, typename Signature > class Method;

// Specialization for signatures with no parameters
template< typename Host, typename Return >
class Method< Host, Return () >
{
public:
  typedef Return (Host::*MethodType)();
  Method( Host * host, MethodType method ) : m_Host(host), m_Method(method) {}

  Value operator()() { return Value( (m_Host->*m_Method)() ); }
private:
  Host       * m_Host;
  MethodType   m_Method;
};
```

Using this Method class on the method which returns something (namely intReturn) would look like:

```
Method< Subject, int () > intMeth( &subject, &Subject::intReturn );
Value intValue = intMeth();
```

However, doing this with the voidReturn method:

```
Method< Subject, void () > voidMeth( &subject, &Subject::voidReturn );
Value voidValue = voidMeth();
```

yields similar errors as above.

One solution is to further partially specialize Method for void return types:

```
template< typename Host >
class Method< Host, void () >
{
public:
  typedef void Return;
  typedef Return (Host::*MethodType)();
  Method( Host * host, MethodType method ) : m_Host(host), m_Method(method) {}

  Value operator()() { return (m_Host->*m_Method)(), Value(); }
private:
  Host       * m_Host;
  MethodType   m_Method;
};
```

Besides it just feeling ugly, I'm also wanting to specialize the Method class for X numbers of signature parameters, which already involves a lot of code duplication (hopefuly Boost.Preprocessor can help here), and then adding a specialization for void return types just doubles that duplication effort.

Is there anyway to avoid this second specialization for void return types?

Comment: +1. This is a very well written question, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Return` and just specialize `operator()` handling. No need to duplicate the whole template.

```
// I think it's a shame if c++0x really gets rid of std::identity. It's soo useful!
template<typename> struct t2t { };

// Specialization for signatures with no parameters
template< typename Host, typename Return >
class Method< Host, Return () >
{
public:
  typedef Return (Host::*MethodType)();
  Method( Host * host, MethodType method ) : m_Host(host), m_Method(method) {}

  Value operator()() { return call(t2t<Return>()); }

private:
  Value call(t2t<void>) { return Value(); }

  template<typename T>
  Value call(t2t<T>) { return Value((m_Host->*m_Method)()); }

private:
  Host       * m_Host;
  MethodType   m_Method;
};
```

Comment: … and the reason for getting rid of `identity` is that defining its `operator()` to use rvalue references instead of `const&` would break too much installed code!

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for! I remember reading about Type2Type awhile ago by Alexandrescu but have since forgot about it.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is absolutely no way to pass a `void`. It is an irregularity in the language.

The function argument list `(void)` is translated as `()`. Bjarne prefers the latter to the former, and begrudgingly allowed the C convention as a very limited kind of syntactic sugar. You can't even substitute a typedef alias of `void`, and you certainly can't have any other arguments.

I personally think this is a bad idea. If you can write `void(expr)`, then you should be able to "initialize" an anonymous argument of type `void`. If you could also write a function with an arbitrary number of `void` arguments, there would be a way to execute a number of expressions in unspecified order, which would express concurrency in a way.

As for handling different-sized argument lists (also known as variadic), see variadic templates in C++0x before you start trying to learn Boost Preprocessor.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. I thought I had seen something in boost.function where they were doing something similar but apparently not. And thanks for the tip on variadic templates, unfortunately I haven't upgraded my compilers (yet).

Comment: "A function argument list with one argument of type void is adjusted to be a list with no arguments." -> actually it's even more strict. It's this way in C99, but in C++ the replacement is purely syntactic: The sequence of tokens "(void)" denotes a zero-parameter list. But for example "(Void)" where "Void" denotes the void type is illegal in C++.